# 97' lancer hestitates under acceleration

Tags: engine, mitsubishi, acceleration, hesitation

I have a 97' lancer with the 1.6 engine, here's the thing, when I press the accelerator slightly it jerks a little no matter if Im moving, or taking off from a stop, If I press it more, like doing a more sporty driving its ok, doesn't do that, the rest of the time works ok, except from the rought idle it always have.
Things I've made:
-Spark plugs check
-Coils and cables check
-EGR check
-Cleaned the whole TB and Iac valve

It has a manual transmission

Comment: How old are the spark plugs?

Comment: They are at least 2 years old, they look as new, no carbon deposits or oil. I haven´t put a lot of millage on them, I don´t use the car as much. I forgot to say that it gets worst with the A/C on